# Lazarus Form resize by code

Tags: forms, lazarus, freepascal

On Arch Linux, using Lazarus 1.6.4, I am trying to hold the form's height constant.

The code below is a minimal example:

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormDblClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormResize(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  h : Integer;
implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormDblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(h.ToString);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
   h := Form1.Height;
   Form1.Height:=200; //please note this line
end;

end.
```

If i comment the marked line out, I can see the change in forms height by double clicking it.

However, if the Marked line is there, then the form still changes it's height, but doesn't come back to 200. Double clicking the from shows the form height is changed to 200. But that change isn't reflect in the form's actual height.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to assign h before setting the height to 200. So why doesn't your double click message do `ShowMessageFmt('height: %d', [Form1.Height]);`?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Even if i did so, Iexpect the  Form1.Height:=200; line to force the form height back to 200. it didnt do so

Comment: Ok, but don't rely on your output message. I don't have your Linux, so I can't check this, sorry.

Comment: FWIW, in Windows, this works fine (height remains 200, no matter what). Can't try in my Ubuntu, right now.

Comment: Just had the opportunity to try in Ubuntu. The height is 200, always, from the start (OnResize seems to be called on showing too). I can't change the height (except for a split second), but I can change the width. And the double click always shows 200. So sorry, but I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis thurns out, its a QT issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing things in formresize get ticklish and you are changing something that will probably fire the resize event itself which could be, well, ticklish??

Anyway, just set minheight and maxheight to 200 and that should do the trick.

Comment: that solved it, thank you. how should / can I anticipate such tickles?

Comment: Hi, you look at an event and avoid changing a property that will fire that event, it then becomes recursive and usually fails, sometimes quietly, sometimes spectacularly. Here you changed the form's height (you resized it) which apparently called FormResize which changes the height which...etc. Similarly changing a checkbox's checked property in its OnChange event will also cause problems for instance. You can do it, but it gets...ticklish. Using flags and so on you can avoid recursive calls but it can be a pain.